# Kohana 3 sessions between functions

Tags: function, session, kohana

I am trying to use session in controller between functions in Kohana 3:

```
public function action_setsession()
    {
       $session = Session::instance();
       $session->set('test1', 'testing1');
       $session->set('test2', 'testing2');
    }

public function action_getsession()
    {
       $session = Session::instance();
       $test1 = $session->get('test1');
       $test2 = $session->get('test2');

       echo 'Test1='.$test1;
       echo 'Test2='.$test2;
    }
```

And I do not get any data in getsession() function. Is it possible to use it in this way at all ? Or what I am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: What is your [adapter](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/sessions#session-adapters) (and does he work properly)? Are you calling both functions in the same script (so no refresh before `get`)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. It should work properly but there are some things to check:

- Are you running `action_setsession` before you run `action_getsession`
- Did you configure your session library properly? See [Session Configuration](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/sessions#session-configuration)

If you checked these things you most likely find the reason why it's not working.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the end of action_setsession() I use redirect. Can redirection mess it up ? As well strange thing that in same controller I use session between controller function and view and it is working fine.

Comment: No that should not be a problem. When you set the session it is set. The the only problem should be misconfiguration.

Comment: Ok, I got. Problem is that I am using facebook php sdk and if I start sessions after FB it gets messed up, it is not working. Solution is to start kohana session before FB session.